# PostgreSQL DROP ROLE throws error: cannot drop role because it is required by the database system

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a role named `service-synapse-postgres` and I want to to run `DROP ROLE "service-synapse-postgres";` on it. I tried the following commands:

```
synapse=# REASSIGN OWNED BY "service-synapse-postgres" TO synapse;
ERROR:  cannot reassign ownership of objects owned by role service-synapse-postgres because they are required by the database system
synapse=# DROP OWNED BY "service-synapse-postgres";
ERROR:  cannot drop objects owned by role service-synapse-postgres because they are required by the database system
synapse=# DROP ROLE "service-synapse-postgres";
ERROR:  cannot drop role service-synapse-postgres because it is required by the database system
```

This is the state of the role `service-synapse-postgres`:

```
\du
                          List of roles
         Role name         |       Attributes        | Member of
---------------------------+-------------------------+-----------
 service-synapse-postgres  | Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't drop "service-synapse-postgres" because it appears to be the boot-strap user (the one created by initdb), which is permanent.

The best you could do is probably drop user synapse, then create another superuser account and use it to do `alter user "service-synapse-postgres" rename to synapse;`

Comment: Take a good look at the error message "***required by the database system***". Then ask yourself: If Postgres requires it but it does not exist then do I have a viable database system? Perhaps the error is just protecting you from complete disaster.

Comment: @Belayer If you rename it, it still exists.  It doesn't care how you spell the name.

Comment: I agree, Postgres is smart enough to figure that out a rename. But the question was how to drop it not how to rename it.  The point is what happens if you manage to to do so and that sometimes an error message is saying you really do not want tot do this.

Comment: How can I find out, why Postgres requires that role? I looked into `\d` and this role did not appear in any database.

Comment: Did you try `\dS` ?

Comment: @jjanes you are correct, at \dS there are some tables etc owned by `service-synapse-postgres`. How can I change the owner from `service-synapse-postgres` to `synapse` on them that I can drop `service-synapse-postgres` afterwards?
I'm currently getting this error: 
`ALTER TABLE pg_statistic OWNER TO synapse; ERROR:  permission denied: "pg_statistic" is a system catalog`

Comment: You can't, other than a full pg_dump and the reload into a better initdb'ed database instance.  The best you can do is merge synaptic into service-synapse-postgres **in that direction**, then drop synaptic and rename service-synapse-postgres.